# VBA Macro "Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set" Can't figure out why

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to modify a scraping macro to click a button on a webpage. I'm getting an error 91 on the below code, and cannot for the life of me figure out why. The object that it doesn't like is the "dd" object. I've tried just about everything I've seen on here so far, so any fresh ideas would be much appreciated!

```
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = True


Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim MyURL As String
Dim Rows As Long, links As Variant, IE As InternetExplorer, link As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim sID As String
Dim rngLinks As Range, rngLink As Range


Dim filterRange As Range
Dim copyRange As Range

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set IE = New InternetExplorer

Rows = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rngLinks = ws1.Range("E2:E" & Rows)
i = 2

With IE
    .Visible = True


        .navigate ("https://www.samplesite.com/account/update")

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:006"))

                Dim doc As Object
                Set doc = IE.document




Dim classNameElem As Variant
Dim tagNameElem As Variant
Set classNameElem = doc.getElementsByClassName("thisisaclass")(0)
If (classNameElem <> Null) Then
   Set tagNameElem = classNameElem.getElementsByTagName("input")(0)
End If
If (tagNameElem <> Null) Then
   tagNameElem.Click
End If




End With





Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

ws1.Activate

Set rngLinks = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Try dropping `Set` from  `Set dd`, or `Dim dd` as an `Object`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've actually tried doing both of those fixes already though. I tried dimming as a string as well.

Comment: The `Click` on the end of the line looks odd. Looks like a function that doesn't return a value.

Comment: The intent is to click a button on a webpage, and I've read that that is the command to do so. Interesting that you say that though, because I have another version that is supposed to do the same thing (click a button on a webpage) that does not error out, but will also not click the button.

Comment: Do you actually need to assign it to *anything*?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow?

Comment: Remove `Set dd = `.

Comment: I will reiterate what @Bathsheba said. You don't need to set a variable to a button click. You can just use the code to click the button. If for some reason you wanted to encapsulate that, you could write a small sub and pass it an object and have it click that object.

Comment: hmm, unfortunately that still isn't working

Answer (score 0):

1) Do not set the result of the click to any variable

2) Change the name of the method to getElementsByTagName:

```
doc.getElementsByClassName("thisclassname")(0).getElementsByTagName("thistagname")(0).Click
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest do as below. Please debug and see if the right hand side equations returning any values

```
Dim classNameElem As Variant 
Dim tagNameElem As Variant                  
 Set classNameElem = doc.getElementsByClassName("thisclassname")(0)
 If (Not classNameElem Is Nothing) Then
   Set tagNameElem = classNameElem.getElementsByTagName("input")(0)
 End If
 If (Not classNameElem Is Nothing) Then
   tagNameElem.Click
 End If
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Siva and MacroMarc, I tried both of your fixes but am still getting the same error. I'm not even sure how it's possible at this point to be getting this error...

Comment: @HenryK, is it possible to post your entire code,so that i can give a try to figure out whats wrong and try for fix

Comment: Sure, I've added the full code (I know it's pretty messy, that's because of how many iterations I've gone through trying to fix it). Thanks!

Comment: @HenryK the site is not opening in my machine. The code i suggested has slight modification please see the edited answer

Comment: @HenryK, using http, im able to open the site, can please let me know the class name you are looking for you just gave "thisclassname"

Comment: Sorry about that, just reflex to not get specific. You wouldn't really be able to manipulate the site though, since it requires an account.